# Units of flow from a line integral

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Given a velocity field $\vec F(x,y)$, the flow along a curve $C$ is given by 
$$\int_C \vec F\cdot \vec T ds= \int_C \vec F\cdot d\vec r,$$
where $\vec r(t)$ is a parametrization of $C$.

What the units of flow? It seems the obvious answer is along the lines of  "$m^2/s$", but I have no intuitive understanding of what that means. I understand that flow is measuring "how much" of something is moving "along the curve $C$." The units, though, befuddle me.

Comment: @Surb F is a velocity field, not a force.

Answer (score 0):

$\vec{F}$ would have the unit $\frac{\text{length}}{\text{time}}$, $\vec{T}$ is a unit vector with no units, and $ds$ would have units of $\text{length}$. So *flow* would have units of $\frac{\text{length}^2}{time}$ because of the product in the integral.

Comment: Usually flow is expressed as "the volume of something per unit of time."

Comment: Sure, "length^2/time" is fine - in my question I wrote it as m^2/s as an example. My issue is "what does that mean?" And I get flow as "volume per unit time" - is the "volume" here implied as $\vec F$ is in the plane with small thickness, giving us in total "length^3/time"? I guess I was hoping for something more intuitive - to me, the units of acceleration given as "distance/time^2" is confusing, though recognizing this as "(distance/time) / time" is more intuitive. I was hoping for a more intuitive understanding of "length^2/time".